# render variable in template vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<li v-for="set in indirect_arr">
 {{set.wp}} -
 {{set.bus1}} -   
 {{set.bus2}}
</li>
```

`indirect_arr` -> array of Objects(say, set).

Object Structure ->

```
set : {
  wp: '',
  bus1: [],
  bus2:[]
}
```

bus1 & bus2 are reflected on dom as Array.

I want them as single elements .

I tried -> `<li v-for="bus in set.bus1">{{bus}}</li>` . Got Error -> set not defined !

Comment: Also tried this -> `<li v-for="bus in indirect_arr.set.bus1">{{bus}}</li>` . Error -> set undefined.

Comment: the code above does not work, because `indirect_arr` is an array, therefore you cannot simply access `set`. It would have to look like this: `... bus in indirect_arr[index].set.bus1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
<li v-for="set in indirect_arr">
  {{set.wp}} -
  <p v-for='bus in set.bus1'> {{bus}} </p> -
  <template v-for='bus in set.bus2'> {{bus}} </template>
</li>
```

`<template>` is an element, which will be removed on render.